# Issue while getting data from firebase realtime database into react redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I'm trying to get data from the firebase **"realtime database"**.

```
words:
0: {somedata},
2: {some data},
3: {some data},
4: {some data},
```

please note that the key 1 does not exists on firebasse.

here is how the data present in the firebase

[image]

The data arrived at the redux reducer correctly like how it preset in firebase "without the key #1", but after dispatching it into the state, I've got a null object for key #1 like the below example.

```
words: [
   0: {data here}
   1: null
   2: {data here}
   3: {data here}
]
```

here is how the data present in redux store:

[image]

here is the reducer:

[image]

here is how the date presents on reducer:

[image]

My question is: why the data is not saved in redux store like the below structure:

```
words: [
   0: {data here}
   2: {data here}
   3: {data here}
   4: {data here}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store an array in Firebase, it actually stores is as an object with separate number keys (so the `0: { ... }, 1: { ... }` in your data).

When retrieve data with sequential, numerical keys from Firebase, it interpret that as an array again.

So when you store/retrieve an entire array, your application code always just sees the array - never the way it is stored as a regular object.

---

Firebase SDKs and the REST API also interpret sequences as an array when there are a few items missing. It "just" sets those indices to `null` as shown in your second snippet.

For more on this, see the vintage blog post: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

---

The best solution when this array coercion gets in your way, is to not use arrays for storing the data. For example, I prefer prefixing those numeric keys with a short string, like `"key0"`, `"key2"`. That way Firebase will never try to convert my data into an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank van Puffelen!!

Your suggestion works well for my situation.